# Run code only after all transitions have ended

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, dom-events

This one's a brain cracker **for me**.

This **Event** will fire up everytime a transition ends, in our case **5 times** because of `backgroundColor, borderTopLeftRadius, borderTopRightRadius...`
which I don't want, I want this event to fire up only after all transitions have ended. here's a snippet:

```js
function changeStyle() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("elem");
  const logs = document.getElementById("logs");
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  elem.style.borderRadius = "30px";

  elem.ontransitionend = () => {
    logs.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", "transition ended");
  }
}
```

```css
#elem {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, border-radius 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="changeStyle()" id="elem">
  click me !
</div>

<span id="logs"></span>
```

Comment: Post your [mcve]

Comment: We can not find your problem if you only provide a little info to us, at least ask the code that is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transitionend` event contains a `propertyName` property, which refers to the property transition that ended. Here, you can examine the event to check which property caused the event to fire. Since the longest transition is the border radius, check if the `propertyName` is one of the border radiuses:

```js
function changeStyle() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("elem");
  const logs = document.getElementById("logs");
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  elem.style.borderRadius = "30px";

  elem.ontransitionend = (e) => {
    if (e.propertyName === "border-bottom-right-radius") {
      logs.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", "transition ended");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#elem {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, border-radius 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="changeStyle()" id="elem">
  click me !
</div>

<span id="logs"></span>
```